# how to remove validate focus on dojox.form.PasswordValidator

Tags: validation, dojo, passwords, focus

Im not sure how to explain this... In the sample code on this [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojox/form/PasswordValidator.html) is a password validation that has the new and verify input box. so you type the new password and now you're confirming the password. Now you want to change the new password without filling the confirm box but you cant because the browser keeps auto focusing the confirm box until it matches the password which you potentially forget.

Long story short, how do I remove the auto focus of the validation in dojo's password validator without refreshing the page or replacing it with 2 validation text boxes?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Dojo bug, and it was apparently fixed in Dojo 1.7.2: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15504

Comment: Is there a way to fix this bug without upgrading the dojo framework from 1.6 -> 1.7.2? like overriding the function? I just started working on Dojo recently and I dont know how to do the overriding.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on creating your own widgets: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/recipes/custom_widget/  In their examples, they extend dijit._Widget. In your case, you'd want to extend dojox.form.PasswordValidator